# Minutes Package: Display the agenda without serifs

Tags: minitoc, minutes

I have written a protocol template using the "Minutes" package. I am already quite satisfied with the display, however, the agenda is output with serifs, so in a different character set. Internally, the Minutes package probably uses a Minitoc environment for this. Now the question: Can I also display the agenda without serifs (I use cmbright)?

Many greetings

Soener

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, textwidth=17cm]{geometry}



\begin{document}




\begin{Protokoll}{Protokoll der Konferenz}
\moderation{NN}
\protokollant{Soener}
\teilnehmer{...}
\fehlend{...}
\gaeste{...}
\sitzungsdatum{01.08.2019}
\sitzungsbeginn{17:00}
\sitzungsende{18:30 Uhr}
\sitzungsort{Raum 30}
\protokollKopf
% ... Tagesordnungspunkte ...

\topic{NN1}

%TODO
TEXT

\topic{NN2}

%TODO
TEXT\\\\


\end{Protokoll}





\end{document}
```

Update:

Thank you for the quick reply. The word "Agenda" is now already displayed without serifs, but not yet the individual agenda items.

[image]

Comment: Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**

The package `minitoc` uses `\rmfamily` in its internal code.

The code added here changes all relevant occurrences to `\sffamily`. The change will be limited to the `minitoc`.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% *****************************************added 
\def\mtcfont{\small\sffamily\upshape\mdseries}
\def\mtcSfont{\small\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}
\def\mtifont{\large\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}
\def\coffeefont{\small\sffamily\slshape\mdseries}
\def\ptcfont{\normalsize\sffamily\upshape\mdseries} % the parttoc
\def\ptcCfont{\normalsize\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}% (chapters)
\def\ptcSfont{\normalsize\sffamily\upshape\mdseries}% (sections)    
\def\ptifont{\Large\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}% titles
\def\ptcSSfont{\small\sffamily\upshape\mdseries}% (subsections)
\def\ptcSSSfont{\small\sffamily\upshape\mdseries}% (subsubsections) 
\let\mtcSSfont\mtcfont 
% ***************************************

\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, textwidth=17cm]{geometry}
    
\begin{document}
        
    \begin{Protokoll}{Protokoll der Konferenz}
        \moderation{NN}
        \protokollant{Soener}
        \teilnehmer{...}
        \fehlend{...}
        \gaeste{...}
        \sitzungsdatum{01.08.2019}
        \sitzungsbeginn{17:00}
        \sitzungsende{18:30 Uhr}
        \sitzungsort{Raum 30}
        \protokollKopf
        % ... Tagesordnungspunkte ...
        
        \topic{NN1}
        
        %TODO
        TEXT
        \subtopic{Unterpunkt zu NN1}
                    
        \topic{NN2}
        
        %TODO
        TEXT\\\\        
        
    \end{Protokoll} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The word "Agenda" is now already displayed without serifs, but not yet the individual agenda items. See the following screenshot.